# Where do you come in your family?

Tags: vocabulary

I am looking for some common questions used to ask about a person's birth order in their family (to ask if he/she is first, second, third, etc. child).
Do the following questions sound natural?
Where do you come in your family?
How-manyth child are you in your family?

Are there any other alternatives?

Comment: No, neither sounds natural. What's wrong with just asking what place they are in their family's birth order as you said?

Comment: OK, "what place are you in your family's birth order?" , Is it the only way to ask that question?

Comment: What is your birth rank or order, Or how is your birth placed among siblings?

Comment: It's not the only way, but it's how I'd expect to see the question phrased, and everyone should understand it. You could also consider splitting it into two questions: "How many children are in your family?" and "Which sibling are you? (oldest, youngest, etc.)"

Comment: I wonder why nobody answers this question there are only comments

Comment: If you are learning English, you may find our sister site [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) better suited to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, the most common way to approach this line of questioning in a conversational setting is:

***"Are you/Were you*** (depending on whether the subject is child/adult) ***The 'big brother/sister' or the 'baby'?"***

In most cases this is a sufficient prompt to the other person that you are inquiring about their birth order. You may also be treated to an overview of their family history/dynamic/dysfunction.

In a non-conversational setting, the easiest way to ascertain the information is:

*Your name:______  Your age:_____*

*Your siblings and their ages:___________________*